# Using VBA if statements to hide/unhide columns with a button

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a clickable toggle button that hides a year's worth of data if it is currently unhidden and unhides it if it is hidden. I know this syntax is incorrect but I am not sure how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Hide_2012()
Dim Yr2012 As Range
    Set Yr2012 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Jobs Calculations").Range("AI:AT")

If Yr2012.Visible = False Then
     Yr2012.Visible = True
Else If Yr2012.Visible = True Then
     Yr2012.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Try it with `.Visible` rather than `.Hidden`

Comment: Missing `end if`. Also, are you sure you want the entire column? Edit: `then` on the wrong lines....

Comment: @Dave I am still getting a syntax error for the whole thing.

Comment: @findwindow I made that change but still am getting an error of Expected Then or Go To

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me. Apparently `hidden` only works on [entire columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx).

```
Dim Yr2012 As Range
Set Yr2012 = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Open Jobs Calculations").Range("A1:B10") 'change range

If Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
     Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ElseIf Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
    Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

Edit per Scott's comment:

```
Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden
```

much more elegant.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I think you can replace the IF statement with this one line `Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Yr2012.EntireColumn.Hidden` I think, not tested.

Answer (score 0):

This modification of @findwindow's answer worked for me:

```
Set Yr2012 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Jobs Calculations").Columns("AI:AT")  ' <- (ie, set range to the desired columns)
```

then you can still reference the "Yr2012" range, without needing ".EntireColumn":

```
If Yr2012.Hidden = False Then ...
```

Just another take on the same idea, to reduce typing :)